# Foundation Framework - Orbit Slider

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, orbit

I have managed to get the Orbit Slider onto my page, but it does not have the timer or the naviagation buttons like the example given on the [Foundation Framework website](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/orbit.php).

I downloaded the framework using Sass and it says in the documentation that the Orbit JS and CSS will be part of my environment already.

How do I get these to show? They do not load when I check using Firebug.

When using Firebug it shows the following:

```
.orbit-wrapper .slider-nav span.right {
    background: url("../images/foundation/orbit/right-arrow.png?1360951464") repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% auto transparent;
    right: 0;
}
```

in `_orbit.scss`.

But is says failed to load image. I don't know how to get the images to load.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you missed the command necessary to unpack the assets you're looking for.  Since you've already got your project started, you just need to run this command:

```
compass install foundation
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compass.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that didn't work. I tried the command and it says I already have it installed. I then updated the files using compass install -r zurb-foundation foundation/upgrade --forceand it still doesn't work. I have a file called app.scss which came with the install and I have uncommetted the following: @import "foundation/components/modules/orbit";, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Did you verify that the files are there?

Comment: There are no files in the sass folder relating to _orbit.scss. I only have _settings.scss and app.scss, plus defaults.scss and settings.scss that I created. There is jquery.foundation.orbit.js in the javascripts folder and an orbit folder in the images folder.

Comment: The images aren't in the orbit folder?  Their manifest is a little different from what I'm used to seeing and I'm not a Ruby programmer but it looks like it *should* have copied the images over.  You can get whatever you're missing directly from their repository: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/master/vendor/assets

Comment: I have the images folfer. I do not have the _orbit.scss. I have now downloaded it and put it in the following location: \sass\foundation\components\modules but it hasn't worked. I have uncommented the @import "foundation/components/modules/orbit in the app.scss

Comment: You aren't supposed to have an _orbit.scss file according to the manifest, it's supposed to stay bundled within the foundation gem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found out what the problem was. The images that were downloaded with the SASS install are corrupted. I downloaded them using the regular install and now it all works fine.